# Collect URL of image using Google sheets and IMPORTXML

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

I am trying use IMPORTXML on google sheets to exact url for images from a long list (4.0K) of webpages in  a website [Source website](https://wbssmedia.com/artists/detail/100)

URLs are in Column A and the formula typically generate three results. I would like a specific URL for the main image on each page.

I get the following output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoA3.png)

Using the XPath below;

`=IMPORTXML($A2, "//img/@src")`

The image reside in the section below;

```html
<section id="single-details" class="news-details artest-detals">
       <div class="wrap">
 
       <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="img-box">
                        <img src="https://wbssmedia.com/artist_images/full_thumb/1798148142MagicSamB1.jpg" style="border-radius: 13px;" alt="">
                    </div>
          </div>
                   </div>   
 
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">

                  <div class="play-video-detals">
                     <div class="page-tital">
                         <h1>Magic Sam</h1>
                     </div>
                     <div class="video-descriotion">
                        <p font-family:="" font-size:=""> </p>

<p color:="" font-family:="" font-size:="" margin-bottom:="" margin-top:=""><span id="Life_and_career">Life and career</span></p>

<p font-family:="" font-size:="">Magic Sam gained a following before being drafted into the U.S. Army. He served six months in prison for desertion and received a dishonorable discharge.</p>

<p font-family:="" font-size:="">Magic Sam&#39;s breakthrough performance was at the Ann Arbor Blues Festival in 1969, which won him many bookings in the United States and Europe.</p>

<p font-family:="" font-size:="">His guitar style, vocals, and songwriting have inspired and influenced many blues musicians. In the film <i>The Blues Brothers</i>, Jake Blues dedicates the band&#39;s performance of "Sweet Home Chicago" to the "late, great Magic Sam".</p>

<p font-family:="" font-size:="">"Magic Sam had a different guitar sound," said his record producer, Willie Dixon. "Most of the guys were playing the straight 12-bar blues thing, but the harmonies that he carried with the chords was a different thing altogether. This tune "All Your Love", he expressed with such an inspirational feeling with his high voice. You could always tell him, even from his introduction to the music."</p>

<h2 font-family:="" font-size:="" margin-top:=""> </h2>

<ul>
 <li>1982, Blues Foundation Blues Music Award for <i>Magic Sam Live</i> in the category Vintage or Reissue Album of the Year (US)</li>
 <li>1982, Blues Foundation Hall of Fame, induction as Performer</li>
 <li>1984, Blues Foundation Hall of Fame, <i>West Side Soul</i> selected in the category Classics of Blues Recordings – Albums</li>
 <li>1990, Blues Foundation Hall of Fame, <i>Black Magic</i> selected in the category Classics of Blues Recordings – Albums</li>
</ul>
<br/>
                       

                     </div>
                      To learn more about the artist, please visit <br/><a target="_blank" href="http://wikipedia.thetimetube.com/?lang=en&q=Magic Sam">http://wikipedia.thetimetube.com/?lang=en&q=Magic Sam</a><p>&nbsp;</p>
                                            <div class="video-view">
                     <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7S5DGqCfk8o" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>                         
                     </div>
                                          
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                         
                                      
                                </div>
                   
                </div>


          <div class="btn-block">
         
                       <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="back-btn">Back</a>
                    </div>
            </div>

       </div>

       <div class="row">
                   


       </div>
              
  </div>

</section>
```

I am very new to much of this and would appricate any help. Ultimately I would like to scrape the image url, rename and download the images into a google drive folder but this is the first hurdle.

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the XPath query:

"/html/body/section/div/div[1]/div/div/img/@src"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).